# tabkey pressed in textfield of javafx

Tags: javafx

I want to have the tab key pressed when the number of inputs in my javafx textfield is filled up to four.

please let me know how to get the answer from upper question.

I'm curious about how to get tab key action.

```js
textfield.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      if(!newValue.matches("[0-9]*") || newValue.length()>4){
       textfield.setText(oldValue);
      }else if(newValue.length()==4) {
       KeyEvent tab = new KeyEvent(keyEvent.getEventType(), null,
                  null, KeyCode.TAB, false, false, false, false);
      }
     });
```

Comment: no, that's most probably not what you want :) Don't mix requirement and presumed solution (aka: x-y-problem). Please state your requirement (you want trigger a focus traversal to the next control?) and then provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what your tried and how you get stuck (vs. just a snippet without context)

Comment: so how do i do?

Comment: search for FocusTraversal - there is no public api but hacks depending on fx version